# Move column B & Q to new tab & then concatenate into new cell

Tags: google-sheets

I need to move columns B (email) & Q (SKUs) into a new tab and then create another column in said tab with the info from B & Q merged or concatenated. All of this triggered when document is opened.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hUaJ3u5T678C9bFauJJLtb8FPVM9BSHLRm8gCxYr624/edit#gid=0

Comment: there is not enough information to help.  Here's a blank sheet, paste in what you have and show your desired results.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hUaJ3u5T678C9bFauJJLtb8FPVM9BSHLRm8gCxYr624/edit

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hUaJ3u5T678C9bFauJJLtb8FPVM9BSHLRm8gCxYr624

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On tab2, cell A1:

`=arrayformula({'TAB1'!B:B,'TAB1'!Q:Q,'TAB1'!B:B&" "&'TAB1'!Q:Q})`

[image]

Comment: Would this be triggered every time a new item is added to TAB1? Or every time the doc opens? TAB1 has a new row every time a purchase is made

Comment: The `arrayformula` is live. It always gets what is on tab1. You can also wrap a `query` function around it to manipulate the date if you need the most recent rows at the top etc.